# how i can make upd server listen for multiple ports?

Tags: java, ports, datagram

I'm have a **`upd client/server`** chat system (text , voice), i would to **listen** for **voice chat** in port and **text chat** in another one

Comment: Is there a problem with creating two sockets and bind them to their respective ports?

Comment: sockets that a datagram you can't create two servers in the same machine

Comment: Of course you can: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket(int)

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind , that exception i found when i run one more server in same machine thank you for help i will see what bind nw :)